# PHP select one data from mysql NOT DISPLAYING

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am trying to display or return the Date value from a selected user

```
function mysql_select_one_data($database, $table, $data, $country, $phone){  
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test123");

    mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT DATE FROM Temp_Users WHERE Country = '+94' AND Phone = '1234539543';";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Date: " . $row["Date"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    return $result;
    }
```

result:

```
Date:
Resource id #5
```

but when I do the query in phpmyadmin it returns

[image]
[image]

I am new in Php and I Don't know what I am doing wrong, Thanks for your help.

Comment: why marked as duplicated? this question is not linked to "Can I use MySQL and MySQLI together [closed] "

Comment: *"I am new in Php and I Don't know what I am doing wrong"* - You're right. The duplicate stands.

Comment: i have edited my content and the result changed but still not displaying

Comment: I need to see what you're using above `mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die (mysql_error());` that you're not showing us.

Comment: I adjusted my answer

Comment: and `$database` is defined as? including others.

Comment: `mysql_select_one_data` Edit: Oh, it's a custom function. Why don't you start by reading the manuals on both mysql and mysqli, setup your db connection correctly then try again. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php - Your code makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, but your code makes no sense at all. Run it without the custom function and read up on the links I've given you above and don't mix MySQL APIs.

Comment: I just wanted to make a custom function bro to select data, I am new in php I just started yesterday and I dont know how to call data from page to page

Comment: I don't even know how you're using `mysql_select_one_data()`. Instead of jumping into the deep end right away, get to learn how an MySQL API works. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `mysqli_` setup the connection as they have it in there, query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and pass db connection to the query. Once you've done that, then you setup a custom function.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I will start reading it. <3 and I didnt notice it was mysqli_ i didnt see it though.

Comment: You're welcome. I've reopened the question since you've changed everything to a single MySQL API. `mysql_` and `mysqli_` don't mix together, same for PDO, remember that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$query = "SELECT DATE FROM Temp_Users WHERE Country = \"+94\" AND Phone = \"1234539543\";";
```

to this

```
$query = "SELECT DATE FROM Temp_Users WHERE Country = '+94' AND Phone = '1234539543';";
```

Change the `echo` command to `echo "Date: $row['DATE']<br>"`

Comment: The result is the same D:

Comment: ah yes, you are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: what do you mean? I am have used many other queries but this query is not working

Comment: just for fun change your mysql into mysqli

Comment: The result is the same I have tried with "DATE", "Date", "date" and nothing changes

Comment: Date:
Array ( [DATE] => Wednesday 8th of April 2015 10:35:47 AM )
Resource id #5

Comment: echo it like `echo "Date: $row['DATE']<br>"`

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'll add the echo adjusted to my answer.